# Pan Background Image Animation

Tags: css

I have a background image that seamlessly tiles.

```
body{background:url('image.png') repeat}
```

I'd like to animate the background so it constantly pans in one direction. The scroll position and contents of the page stays the same, but the background is constantly and indefinitely pans in one specified direction at one speed. As the image seamlessly tiles, it never runs out of image.

How can I do this? [This seems promising](https://codepen.io/lordgiotto/pen/winID), but the background just moves one non-tiling image back and forth. [This](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/ken_burns_effect_css.htm) and [this](http://devblog.lastrose.com/css-hero-image-pan/) is more or less the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a css keyframe animation to change the background position and set [`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) to `infinite`?

```css
@keyframes panno {
  from {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 100%;
  }
}

#pan {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  animation: panno linear 3s infinite  
}
```

```html
<div id="pan">PANNO!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This gets me very close. I see I can change the direction I want to pan by changing the to position in the keyframes, for example, panning vertically would be 0% 100%. And then I can change the speed based on how many seconds I want it to take. My only issue now is I notice the background jumping at the end of each iteration, even though the background image is seamless. I'm using an image from https://www.transparenttextures.com/ . Any idea what's causing the jumping?

Comment: I figured it out. I changed it from 100% 100% to the actual dimensions of the image tile. Thank you so much for your help on this!